# Почему в jQuery после функции и скобок идет точка и снова функции и скобки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я учу js после c++, и не могу понять выражений в jquery, когда очень длинная строка и много функций с аргументами, разделенные запятыми. Объясните пожалуйста структуру всего этого. Насколько я понимаю, это что-то вроде объектов с параметрами для конструкторов
Например:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table tr:even").addClass('stripe');
});
```

Это просто рандомный пример, как такое может быть - функции со своими методами? Надеюсь вопрос вы поняли

Comment: Это не "функции со своими методами", а "результат вызова функции с его (результатa) методами".

Comment: что такое "его"? просто не понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это таков базовый синтаксис библиотеки **[jquery](https://html5css.ru/jquery/jquery_syntax.php)**, который выглядит так:

```
$ (селектор). действие()

- Знак $ для определения/доступа к jQuery
- A (селектор) для «запроса (или поиска)» HTML-элементов
- действие jQuery (), выполняемое над элементом (ами)
```

Как правило, после того, как написали доллар и в скобках селектор, то выполняется функция данной библиотеки, которая парсит селектор и **возвращает jquery объект** . А у объектов, конечно же, есть свои методы. Собственно дальше "действие()" - это вызов метода объекта. Методы у объекта вызываются через точку

В случае с `$(document).ready(`  методом будет `ready`, где аргументом будет анонимная функция

---

Также, для более удобного использования библиотеки сделан так называемый **["chaining"](https://html5css.ru/jquery/jquery_chaining.php)**, когда методы объекта можно вызывать один за другим. Как правило в этой библиотеке методы возвращают всегда сам jquery объект, поэтому возможны конструкции вида:

```
$('.test').eq(1).find('p').closest('a').show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Это не "функции со своими методами", а "результат вызова функции с его (результатa) методами".

```
$(document).ready(...
```

Функция `$`, вызванная с параметром `document`, возвращает объект, у которого есть метод `ready`.

```
let o = $(document);
o.ready(...
```

---

```
let tr = $("table tr:even");
tr = tr.addClass('stripe');
tr.show();
```

или

```
$("table tr:even").addClass('stripe').show();
```

Comment: спасибо помог)))

Comment: @Netervey Пожалуйста. "Галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Демо / дополнение к остальным ответам:

**С++**

```
class jQueryWrap
{
    public:
    int x;
    
    jQueryWrap(int x)
    {
        this -> x = x;
    }
    
    jQueryWrap* add(int x)
    {
        this -> x += x;
        return this;
    }
    
    jQueryWrap* mul(int x)
    {
        this -> x *= x;
        return this;
    }
};

jQueryWrap* $(int x)
{
    return new jQueryWrap(x);
}

int main()
{
    jQueryWrap* bubu = $(5) -> add(5) -> mul(2) -> add(5) -> mul(2);
    
    cout << bubu -> x; // 50

    return 0;
}
```

**JS**

```js
function $(x) {
  return new jQueryWrap(x);
}

class jQueryWrap {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  add(x) {
    this.x += x;
    return this;
  }

  mul(x) {
    this.x *= x;
    return this;
  }
}

/***/
let bubu = $(5).add(5).mul(2).add(5).mul(2);

console.log(bubu.x); // 50
```

Comment: * Практически не знаю С++. Возможно, у него тоже возможны вызовы "через точку". Гугл пока не подсказал ничего подходящего) Ключевым моментом является `return this`